# Given a vector or list,how to make a symmetric matrix filled with numbers starting from one?

Tags: python, r, tidyverse

Given some items, say, "a","b","c". I want to make a symmetric matrix looks like this:

```
    a   b   c
a   1   2   3
b   2   4   5
c   3   5   6
```

The matrix is filled with a range of numbers starting from number one. Because the matrix is symmetrical, the values above the diagonal should be identical to those below the diagonal. In addition, I also want to fill numbers into the diagonal.

**Update**: I have finish the job with Python, but I am a novice at Python, my code may be quite redundant. **I also hope to receive answers writing with R.**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

var = ["a","b","c"]
mylist = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(var, 2))

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist,columns = ["col_1","col_2"])
df["num"] = list(range(1,len(df['col_1'])+1))

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2["col_1"] = df["col_2"]
df2["col_2"] = df["col_1"]
df2["num"] = df["num"]

mydf = df.append(df2)
mydf['label'] = mydf[['col_1', 'col_2']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x), axis=1)

mydf = mydf[["label","num"]]


mylist_2 = list(itertools.product(var, repeat=2))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(mylist_2,columns = ["col_1","col_2"])
df_2["label"] = df_2[['col_1', 'col_2']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x), axis=1)

new_df = pd.merge(df_2[["label"]],mydf,on = "label",how = "inner").drop_duplicates()

new_list = list(new_df.num)
my_array = np.asarray(new_list).reshape(len(var),len(var))

matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(my_array,index=var,columns=var)
```

Comment: What is the rule to determine the relationship between `a` and `b` ?

Comment: Also you've tagged both R and Python? Have you tried anything so far and can you post your code?

Comment: You want a symmetric matrix given what? A square matrix? A vector?

Comment: As @kosnik said above, how is the value of the matrix determined? Is it an existing built-in function or something you will write? Is it a vectorized function?

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you:

```
a,b,c = [1,2,3]
val = [a,b,c]
for i in val:
    if i==a:
        lst = [a,b,c]
    else:
        lst = [i,b+i,c+i]
    print(*lst)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
2 4 5
3 5 6
```

Comment: Your solution assumes that the values in columns `b` and `c` are a function of the values in column `a`. This is not the kind of relationship described in the question.

Comment: Does it though? `i` changes in each iteration, so effectively: `[[a,b,c],[b,b+b,c+b],[c,b+c,c+c]]`. Isn't that what the op wants?

Comment: Sorry, cause I haven't explained my question clearly at the beginning, your answer is not quite suitable.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Sorry I didn't phrase my disagreement correctly but I ran out of time for editing, so I just left it.

Answer (score 1):

```
m <- outer(1:3,1:3,"+")
m[,1] <- 1:3
m[1,] <- 1:3
```

Without further detailed information, I can only help you by above

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario, you create an empty square matrix as long and wide as the vector, then iterate for all the combinations of `[i,j]` (row and column index) and calculate the value of each cell.

If it's symmetric you can skip iterations on one side of the diagonal: only calculate for combinations where `i <= j` and fill the value for `[i,j]` and `[j,i]` in the same iteration.

EDIT to include some code:

```
vec <- c(1,2,3)
names(vec) <- c("a", "b", "c")
relate <- function(x,y) { x + y }
len <- length(vec)
mat <- matrix(rep(NA_real_, len^2), ncol=len)
for(i in 1:len){
  for(j in i:len){   # Do not compute symmetrical lower half. 
    # Fill in with mirrored values.
    mat[i,j] <- mat[j,i] <- relate(vec[i], vec[j])
    # Omit "mat[j,i] <-" to get a triangular matrix
  }
}
colnames(mat) <- names(vec)
rownames(mat) <- names(vec)
mat

#    a b c
# a  2 3 4
# b  3 4 5
# c  4 5 6
```

EDIT 2 because editing in-place is better for large structures

```
library(data.table)
vec <- c(1,2,3)
names(vec) <- c("a", "b", "c")
relate <- function(x,y) { x + y }
len <- length(vec)
mat <- as.data.table(matrix(rep(NA_real_, len^2), ncol=len))
for(i in 1:len){
  for(j in i:len){
    res <- relate(vec[i], vec[j])
    set(mat, i, j, res)
    # set(mat, j, i, res)  # Omitting the second assignment to get a triangular result instead.
  }
}
names(mat) <- names(vec)
mat[, rowID := names(vec)] # data.table uses only numeric index for rows
mat

#     a  b c rowID
# 1:  2  3 4     a
# 2: NA  4 5     b
# 3: NA NA 6     c
```

You can cast the final data.table back to matrix and assign the rownames if you need it strictly in matrix format.

EDIT 3 for completeness

There are probably implemented functions that do this sort of thing, with which I am not familiar enough to venture a solution. The tidyverse `purrr::map2()` family of functions is a likely candidate for replacing the nested `for` loops https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html . My understanding however is that the difference is mainly readability and volume of code rather than actual performance.

Comment: Can you provide some code examples to show how you would achieve what you're suggesting?

Comment: I ewas in a crunch, so I assumed that people who can code in two languages are familiar with 2D indexing and basic looping constructs. I'm now editing it to include code.